# What is the best way to decompose a QDir into a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qdir

I am trying to turn a QDir which can contain relative or absolute paths into a list of folders in a QStringList like this:

```
const QString path = dir.path ();
return path.split (QRegExp ("[\\/]+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

This ideally would turn a path like C:\foo\bar into a list of strings "C:", "foo", and "bar"

Is there a better way to do this that is already implemented in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
QDir::toNativeSeparators(dir.path()).split(QDir::separator(), 
                         QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

That way you avoid the need for a regexp.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the docs but they state that QDir::path "Returns the path. This may contain symbolic links, but never contains redundant ".", ".." or multiple separators." Also, doesn't cannonicalPath do the wrong thing on relative paths?

Comment: So does that mean that Qt doesn't have a standard way to do this?

Comment: No, Qt does not have a standard way to do this, because most applications don't care what goes into a path.